# Calculating precision, recall, and F-measure for Logistic Regression classifier

Tags: python-3.x, sentiment-analysis, precision-recall

I have a labeled and clean dataset for sentiment analysis, and I used logistic regression for classification. Here is my code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

    xl = pd.ExcelFile('d:/data.xlsx')
    df3 = xl.parse("Sheet1")

    cl_data, sent = df3['Clean-Reviews'].fillna(' '), df3['Sentiment']
    sent_train, sent_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cl_data, sent, 
    test_size=0.25, random_state=1000)

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    vectorizer.fit(sent_train)

    X_train = vectorizer.transform(sent_train)
    X_test  = vectorizer.transform(sent_test)


   classifier = LogisticRegression()
   classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

when I try to calculate precision, recall, and F-measure:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix


print(f1_score(X_test, y_test, average="macro"))
print(precision_score(X_test, y_test, average="macro"))
print(recall_score(X_test, y_test, average="macro"))
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Can anyone tell what's the problem here? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

accuracy is measured between predicted and true value, and in your code x_test is not a predicted value. it should be

```
y_pred =  classifier.predict(x_test)
print(f1_score(y_test,y_pred, average="macro"))
```